# Lambda function times out when connecting to a DocumentDB cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-documentdb

When I run this Lambda function:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

export const handler = async (event: any) => {
  // Connection URI for the DocumentDB cluster
  const uri = 'mongodb://<myusername>:<mypassword>@.cluster-cuz2po50vpwx.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?tls=true&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false';

  try {
    // Create a new MongoClient
    const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
      tls: true,
      tlsCAFile: 'global-bundle.pem' // Specify the DocDB cert
    });
    console.log('client', client);

    // Connect to the DocumentDB cluster
    const connection = await client.connect();
    console.log('connection', connection);

    // Select the database and collection to perform the find operation
    const database = client.db('test');
    console.log('database', database);
    const collection = database.collection('loads');
    console.log('collection', collection);

    // Perform the find operation
    const documents = await collection.find({}).toArray();

    // Log the retrieved documents
    console.log(documents);
    console.log('Hello');

    // Close the connection
    await client.close();

    // Return a successful response
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: 'Documents retrieved successfully',
    };
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any errors that occurred during the operation
    console.error('Error:', error);

    // Return an error response
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: 'Error retrieving documents',
    };
  }
};
```

I get the following error and log:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "2023-06-13T18:12:18.655Z 6fda03e6-8f0c-4350-8063-f7b1fc74da5a Task timed out after 3.02 seconds"
}
```

```
  2023-06-13T13:12:15.154-05:00   INIT_START Runtime Version: nodejs:18.v7 Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1::runtime:26e9402591d9c467cdcc7355f843d61968f36ecb6e9ef5ab253cc21163343275

2023-06-13T13:12:15.633-05:00   START RequestId: 6fda03e6-8f0c-4350-8063-f7b1fc74da5a Version: $LATEST

2023-06-13T13:12:15.914-05:00   2023-06-13T18:12:15.914Z 6fda03e6-8f0c-4350-8063-f7b1fc74da5a INFO client <ref *1> MongoClient { _events: [Object: null prototype] {}, _eventsCount: 0, _maxListeners: undefined, mongoLogger: MongoLogger { componentSeverities: { command: 'off', topology: 'off', serverSelection: 'off', connection: 'off', default: 'off' }, maxDocumentLength: 1000, logDestination: Socket { connecting: false, _hadError: false, _parent: null, _host: null, _closeAfterHandlingError: false, _readableState: [ReadableState], _events: [Object: null prototype], _eventsCount: 1, _maxListeners: undefined, _writableState: [WritableState], allowHalfOpen: false, _sockname: null, _pendingData: null, _pendingEncoding: '', server: null, _server: null, _type: 'pipe', fd: 2, _isStdio: true, destroySoon: [Function: destroy], _destroy: [Function: dummyDestroy], [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 7, [Symbol(kHandle)]: [Pipe], [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0, [Symbol(timeout)]: null, [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null, [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null, [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null, [Symbol(kCapture)]: false, [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false, [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: false, [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 0, [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0, [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0 } }, s: { url: 'mongodb://LambdaPOC1:DocDBTest1@.cluster-cuz2po50vpwx.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?tls=true&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false', bsonOptions: { raw: false, promoteLongs: true, promoteValues: true, promoteBuffers: false, ignoreUndefined: false, bsonRegExp: false, serializeFunctions: false, fieldsAsRaw: {}, enableUtf8Validation: true }, namespace: MongoDBNamespace { db: 'admin', collection: undefined }, hasBeenClosed: false, sessionPool: ServerSessionPool { client: [Circular *1], sessions: [List] }, activeSessions: Set(0) {}, options: [Getter], readConcern: [Getter], writeConcern: [Getter], readPreference: [Getter], logger: [Getter], isMongoClient: [Getter] }, [Symbol(kCapture)]: false, [Symbol(options)]: [Object: null prototype] { hosts: [ new HostAddress('.cluster-cuz2po50vpwx.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017') ], credentials: MongoCredentials { username: 'LambdaPOC1', password: 'DocDBTest1', source: 'admin', mechanism: 'DEFAULT', mechanismProperties: {} }, compressors: [ 'none' ], connectTimeoutMS: 30000, directConnection: false, driverInfo: {}, enableUtf8Validation: true, forceServerObjectId: false, heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000, keepAlive: true, keepAliveInitialDelay: 120000, loadBalanced: false, localThresholdMS: 15, logger: Logger { className: 'MongoClient' }, maxConnecting: 2, maxIdleTimeMS: 0, maxPoolSize: 100, minPoolSize: 0, minHeartbeatFrequencyMS: 500, monitorCommands: false, noDelay: true, pkFactory: { createPk: [Function: createPk] }, raw: false, readPreference: ReadPreference { mode: 'secondaryPreferred', tags: undefined, hedge: undefined, maxStalenessSeconds: undefined, minWireVersion: undefined }, replicaSet: 'rs0', retryReads: true, retryWrites: false, serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 30000, socketTimeoutMS: 0, srvMaxHosts: 0, srvServiceName: 'mongodb', tls: true, ca: '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' + 'MIIEEjCCAvqgAwIBAgIJAM2ZN/+nPi27MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGVMQswCQYD\n' + 'VQQGEwJVUzEQMA4GA1UEBwwHU2VhdHRsZTETMBEGA1UECAwKV2FzaGluZ3RvbjEi\n' + 'MCAGA1UECgwZQW1hem9uIFdlYiBTZXJ2aWNlcywgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECwwKQW1h\n' + 'em9uIFJEUzEmMCQGA1UEAwwdQW1hem9uIFJEUyBhZi1zb3V0aC0xIFJvb3QgQ0Ew\n' + 'HhcNMTkxMDI4MTgwNTU4WhcNMjQxMDI2MTgwNTU4WjCBlTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMx\n' + 'EDAOBgNVBAcMB1NlYXR0bGUxEzARBgNVBAgMCldhc2hpbmd0b24xIjAgBgNVBAoM\n' + 'GUFtYXpvbiBXZWIgU2VydmljZXMsIEluYy4xEzARBgNVBAsMCkFtYXpvbiBSRFMx\n' + 'JjAkBgNVBAMMHUFtYXpvbiBSRFMgYWYtc291dGgtMSBSb290IENBMIIBIjANBgkq\n' + 'hkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAwR2351uPMZaJk2gMGT+1sk8HE9MQh2rc\n' + '/sCnbxGn2p1c7Oi9aBbd/GiFijeJb2BXvHU+TOq3d3Jjqepq8tapXVt4ojbTJNyC\n' + 'J5E7r7KjTktKdLxtBE1MK25aY+IRJjtdU6vG3KiPKUT1naO3xs3yt0F76WVuFivd\n' + '9OHv2a+KHvPkRUWIxpmAHuMY9SIIMmEZtVE7YZGx5ah0iO4JzItHcbVR0y0PBH55\n' + 'arpFBddpIVHCacp1FUPxSEWkOpI7q0AaU4xfX0fe1BV5HZYRKpBOIp1TtZWvJD+X\n' + 'jGUtL1BEsT5vN5g9MkqdtYrC+3SNpAk4VtpvJrdjraI/hhvfeXNnAwIDAQABo2Mw\n' + 'YTAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUEEi/\n' + 'WWMcBJsoGXg+EZwkQ0MscZQwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUEEi/WWMcBJsoGXg+EZwkQ0Ms\n' + 'cZQwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAGDZ5js5Pc/gC58LJrwMPXFhJDBS8QuDm23C\n' + 'FFUdlqucskwOS3907ErK1ZkmVJCIqFLArHqskFXMAkRZ2PNR7RjWLqBs+0znG5yH\n' + 'hRKb4DXzhUFQ18UBRcvT6V6zN97HTRsEEaNhM/7k8YLe7P8vfNZ28VIoJIGGgv9D\n' + 'wQBBvkxQ71oOmAG0AwaGD0ORGUfbYry9Dz4a4IcUsZyRWRMADixgrFv6VuETp26s\n' + '/+z+iqNaGWlELBKh3iQCT6Y/1UnkPLO42bxrCSyOvshdkYN58Q2gMTE1SVTqyo8G\n' + 'Lw8lLAz9bnvUSgHzB3jRrSx6ggF/WRMRYlR++y6LXP4SAsSAaC0=\n' + '-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n' + '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' + 'MIIEEjCCAvqgAwIBAgIJAJYM4LxvTZA6MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGVMQswCQYD\n' + 'VQQGEwJVUzEQMA4GA1UEBwwHU2VhdHRsZTETMBEGA1UECAwKV2FzaGluZ3RvbjEi\n' + 'MCAGA1UECgwZQW1hem9uIFdlYiBTZXJ2aWNlcywgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECwwKQW1h\n' + 'em9uIFJEUzEmMCQGA1UEAwwdQW1hem9uIFJEUyBldS1zb3V0aC0xIFJvb3QgQ0Ew\n' + 'HhcNMTkxMDMwMjAyMDM2WhcNMjQxMDI4MjAyMDM2WjCBlTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMx\n' + 'EDAOBgNVBAcMB1NlYXR0bGUxEzARBgNVBAgMCldhc2hpbmd0b24xIjAgBgNVBAoM\n' + 'GUFtYXpvbiBXZWIgU2VydmljZXMsIEluYy4xEzARBgNVBAsMCkFtYXpvbiBSRFMx\n' + 'JjAkBgNVBAMMHUFtYXpvbiBSRFMgZXUtc291dGgtMSBSb290IENBMIIBIjANBgkq\n' + 'hkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAqM921jXCXeqpRNCS9CBPOe5N7gMaEt+D\n' + 's5uR3riZbqzRlHGiF1jZihkXfHAIQewDwy+Yz+Oec1aEZCQMhUHxZJPusuX0cJfj\n' + 'b+UluFqHIijL2TfXJ3D0PVLLoNTQJZ8+GAPECyojAaNuoHbdVqxhOcznMsXIXVFq\n' + 'yVLKDGvyKkJjai/iSPDrQMXufg3kWt0ISjNLvsG5IFXgP4gttsM8i0yvRd4QcHoo\n' + 'DjvH7V3cS+CQqW5SnDrGnHToB0RLskE1ET+oNOfeN9PWOxQprMOX/zmJhnJQlTqD\n' + 'QP7jcf7SddxrKFjuziFiouskJJyNDsMjt1Lf60+oHZhed2ogTeifGwIDAQABo2Mw\n' + 'YTAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUFBAF\n' + 'cgJe/BBuZiGeZ8STfpkgRYQwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUFBAFcgJe/BBuZiGeZ8STfpkg\n' + 'RYQwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAKAYUtlvDuX2UpZW9i1QgsjFuy/ErbW0dLHU\n' + 'e/IcFtju2z6RLZ+uF+5A8Kme7IKG1hgt8s+w9TRVQS/7ukQzoK3TaN6XKXRosjtc\n' + 'o9Rm4gYWM8bmglzY1TPNaiI4HC7546hSwJhubjN0bXCuj/0sHD6w2DkiGuwKNAef\n' + 'yTu5vZhPkeNyXLykxkzz7bNp2/PtMBnzIp+WpS7uUDmWyScGPohKMq5PqvL59z+L\n' + 'ZI3CYeMZrJ5VpXUg3fNNIz/83N3G0sk7wr0ohs/kHTP7xPOYB0zD7Ku4HA0Q9Swf\n' + 'WX0qr6UQgTPMjfYDLffI7aEId0gxKw1eGYc6Cq5JAZ3ipi/cBFc=\n' + '-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n' + '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' + 'MIIEEjCCAvqgAwIBAgIJANew34ehz5l8MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGVMQswCQYD\n' + 'VQQGEwJVUzEQMA4GA1UEBwwHU2VhdHRsZTETMBEGA1UECAwKV2FzaGluZ3RvbjEi\n' + 'MCAGA1UECgwZQW1hem9uIFdlYiBTZXJ2aWNlcywgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECwwKQW1h\n' + 'em9uIFJEUzEmMCQGA1UEAwwdQW1hem9uIFJEUyBtZS1zb3V0aC0xIFJvb3QgQ0Ew\n' + 'HhcNMTkwNTEwMjE0ODI3WhcNMjQwNTA4MjE0ODI3WjCBlTELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMx\n' + 'EDAOBgNVBAcMB1NlYXR0bGUxEzARBgNVBAgMCldhc2hpbmd0b24xIjAgBgNVBAoM\n' + 'GUFtYXpvbiBXZWIgU2VydmljZXMsIEluYy4xEzARBgNVBAsMCkFtYXpvbiBSRFMx\n' + 'JjAkBgNVBAMMHUFtYXpvbiBSRFMgbWUtc291dGgtMSBSb290IENBMIIBIjANBgkq\n' + 'hkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAp7BYV88MukcY+rq0r79+C8UzkT30fEfT\n' + 'aPXbx1d6M7uheGN4FMaoYmL+JE1NZPaMRIPTHhFtLSdPccInvenRDIatcXX+jgOk\n' + 'UA6lnHQ98pwN0pfDUyz/Vph4jBR9LcVkBbe0zdoKKp+HGbMPRU0N2yNrog9gM5O8\n' + 'gkU/3O2csJ/OFQNnj4c2NQloGMUpEmedwJMOyQQfcUyt9CvZDfIPNnheUS29jGSw\n' + 'ERpJe/AENu8Pxyc72jaXQuD+FEi2Ck6lBkSlWYQFhTottAeGvVFNCzKszCntrtqd\n' + 'rdYUwurYsLTXDHv9nW2hfDUQa0mhXf9gNDOBIVAZugR9NqNRNyYLHQIDAQABo2Mw\n' + 'YTAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAdBgNVHQ4EFgQU54cf\n' + 'DjgwBx4ycBH8+/r8WXdaiqYwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAU54cfDjgwBx4ycBH8+/r8WXda\n' + 'iqYwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAIIMTSPx/dR7jlcxggr+O6OyY49Rlap2laKA\n' + 'eC/XI4ySP3vQkIFlP822U9Kh8a9s46eR0uiwV4AGLabcu0iKYfXjPkIprVCqeXV7\n' + 'ny9oDtrbflyj7NcGdZLvuzSwgl9SYTJp7PVCZtZutsPYlbJrBPHwFABvAkMvRtDB\n' + 'hitIg4AESDGPoCl94sYHpfDfjpUDMSrAMDUyO6DyBdZH5ryRMAs3lGtsmkkNUrso\n' + 'aTW6R05681Z0mvkRdb+cdXtKOSuDZPoe2wJJIaz3IlNQNSrB5TImMYgmt6iAsFhv\n' + '3vfTSTKrZDNTJn4ybG6pq1zWExoXsktZPylJly6R3RBwV6nwqBM=\n' + '-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n' + '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' + 'MIIEBjCCAu6gAwIBAgIJAMc0ZzaSUK51MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGPMQswCQYD\n' + 'VQQGEwJVUzEQMA4GA1UEBwwHU2VhdHRsZTETMBEGA1UECAwKV2FzaGluZ3RvbjEi\n' + 'MCAGA1UECgwZQW1hem9uIFdlYiBTZXJ2aWNlcywgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECwwKQW1h\n' + 'em9uIFJEUzEgMB4GA1UEAwwXQW1hem9uIFJEUyBSb290IDIwMTkgQ0EwHhcNMTkw\n' + 'ODIyMTcwODUwWhcNMjQwODIyMTcwODUwWjCBjzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEDAOBgNV\n' + 'BAcMB1NlYXR0bGUxEzARBgNVBAgMCldhc2hpbmd0b24xIjAgBgNVBAoMGUFtYXpv\n' + 'biBXZWIgU2VydmljZXMsIEluYy4xEzARBgNVBAsMCkFtYXpvbiBSRFMxIDAeBgNV\n' + 'BAMMF0FtYXpvbiBSRFMgUm9vdCAyMDE5IENBMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOC\n' + 'AQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEArXnF/E6/Qh+ku3hQTSKPMhQQlCpoWvnIthzX6MK3p5a0eXKZ\n' + 'oWIjYcNNG6UwJjp4fUXl6glp53Jobn+tWNX88dNH2n8DVbppSwScVE2LpuL+94vY\n' + '0EYE/XxN7svKea8YvlrqkUBKyxLxTjh+U/KrGOaHxz9v0l6ZNlDbuaZw3qIWdD/I\n' + '6aNbGeRUVtpM6P+bWIoxVl/caQylQS6CEYUk+CpVyJSkopwJlzXT07tMoDL5WgX9\n' + 'O08KVgDNz9qP/IGtAcRduRcNioH3E9v981QO1zt/Gpb2f8NqAjUUCUZzOnij6mx9\n' + 'McZ+9cWX88CRzR0vQODWuZscgI08NvM69Fn2SQIDAQABo2MwYTAOBgNVHQ8BAf8E\n' + 'BAMCAQYwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUc19g2LzLA5j0Kxc0LjZa\n' + 'pmD/vB8wHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUc19g2LzLA5j0Kxc0LjZapmD/vB8wDQYJKoZIhvcN\n' + 'AQELBQADggEBAHAG7WTmyjzPRIM85rVj+fWHsLIvqpw6DObIjMWokpliCeMINZFV\n' + 'ynfgBKsf1ExwbvJNzYFXW6dihnguDG9VMPpi2up/ctQTN8tm9nDKOy08uNZoofMc\n' + 'NUZxKCEkVKZv+IL4oHoeayt8egtv3ujJM6V14AstMQ6SwvwvA93EP/Ug2e4WAXHu\n' + 'cbI1NAbUgVDqp+DRdfvZkgYKryjTWd/0+1fS8X1bBZVWzl7eirNVnHbSH2ZDpNuY\n' + '0SBd8dj5F6ld3t58ydZbrTHze7JJOd8ijySAp4/kiu9UfZWuTPABzDa/DSdz9Dk/\n' + 'zPW4CXXvhLmE02TA9/HeCw3KEHIwicNuEfw=\n' + '-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n' + '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' + 'MIIEEDCCAvigAwIBAgIJAKFMXyltvuRdMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGUMQswCQYD\n' + 'VQQGEwJVUzEQMA4GA1UEBwwHU2VhdHRsZTETMBEGA1UECAwKV2FzaGluZ3RvbjEi\n' + 'MCAGA1UECgwZQW1hem9uIFdlYiBTZXJ2aWNlcywgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECwwKQW1h\n' + 'em9uIFJEUzElMCMGA1UEAwwcQW1hem9uIFJEUyBCZXRhIFJvb3QgMjAxOSBDQTAe\n' + 'Fw0xOTA4MTkxNzM4MjZaFw0yNDA4MTkxNzM4MjZaMIGUMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEQ\n' + 'MA4GA1UEBwwHU2VhdHRsZTETMBEGA1UECAwKV2FzaGluZ3RvbjEiMCAGA1UECgwZ\n' + 'QW1hem9uIFdlYiBTZXJ2aWNlcywgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECwwKQW1hem9uIFJEUzEl\n' + 'MCMGA1UEAwwcQW1hem9uIFJEUyBCZXRhIFJvb3QgMjAxOSBDQTCCASIwDQYJKoZI\n' + 'hvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAMkZdnIH9ndatGAcFo+DppGJ1HUt4x+zeO+0\n' + 'ZZ29m0sfGetVulmTlv2d5b66e+QXZFWpcPQMouSxxYTW08TbrQiZngKr40JNXftA\n' + 'atvzBqIImD4II0ZX5UEVj2h98qe/ypW5xaDN7fEa5e8FkYB1TEemPaWIbNXqchcL\n' + 'tV7IJPr3Cd7Z5gZJlmujIVDPpMuSiNaal9/6nT9oqN+JSM1fx5SzrU5ssg1Vp1vv\n' + '5Xab64uOg7wCJRB9R2GC9XD04odX6VcxUAGrZo6LR64ZSifupo3l+R5sVOc5i8NH\n' + 'skdboTzU9H7+oSdqoAyhIU717PcqeDum23DYlPE2nGBWckE+eT8CAwEAAaNjMGEw\n' + 'DgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgEGMA8GA1UdEwEB/wQFMAMBAf8wHQYDVR0OBBYEFK2hDBWl\n' + 'sbHzt/EHd0QYOooqcFPhMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFK2hDBWlsbHzt/EHd0QYOooqcFPh\n' + 'MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQAO/718k8EnOqJDx6wweUscGTGL/QdKXUzTVRAx\n' + 'JUsjNUv49mH2HQVEW7oxszfH6cPCaupNAddMhQc4C/af6GHX8HnqfPDk27/yBQI+\n' + 'yBBvIanGgxv9c9wBbmcIaCEWJcsLp3HzXSYHmjiqkViXwCpYfkoV3Ns2m8bp+KCO\n' + 'y9XmcCKRaXkt237qmoxoh2sGmBHk2UlQtOsMC0aUQ4d7teAJG0q6pbyZEiPyKZY1\n' + 'XR/UVxMJL0Q4iVpcRS1kaNCMfqS2smbLJeNdsan8pkw1dvPhcaVTb7CvjhJtjztF\n' + 'YfDzAI5794qMlWxwilKMmUvDlPPOTen8NNHkLwWvyFCH7Doh\n' + '-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n' + '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' + 'MIIEFjCCAv6gAwIBAgIJAMzYZJ+R9NBVMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGXMQswCQYD\n' + 'VQQGEwJVUzEQMA4GA1UEBwwHU2VhdHRsZTETMBEGA1UECAwKV2FzaGluZ3RvbjEi\n' + 'MCAGA1UECgwZQW1hem9uIFdlYiBTZXJ2aWNlcywgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECwwKQW1h\n' + 'em9uIFJEUzEoMCYGA1UEAwwfQW1hem9uIFJEUyBQcmV2aWV3IFJvb3QgMjAxOSBD\n' + 'QTAeFw0xOTA4MjEyMjI5NDlaFw0yNDA4MjEyMjI5NDlaMIGXMQswCQYDVQQGEwJV\n' + 'UzEQMA4GA1UEBwwHU2VhdHRsZTETMBEGA1UECAwKV2FzaGluZ3RvbjEiMCAGA1UE\n' + 'CgwZQW1hem9uIFdlYiBTZXJ2aWNlcywgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECwwKQW1hem9uIFJE\n' + 'UzEoMCYGA1UEAwwfQW1hem9uIFJEUyBQcmV2aWV3IFJvb3QgMjAxOSBDQTCCASIw\n' + 'DQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAM7kkS6vjgKKQTPynC2NjdN5aPPV\n' + 'O71G0JJS/2ARVBVJd93JLiGovVJilfWYfwZCs4gTRSSjrUD4D4HyqCd6A+eEEtJq\n' + 'M0DEC7i0dC+9WNTsPszuB206Jy2IUmxZMIKJAA1NHSbIMjB+b6/JhbSUi7nKdbR/\n' + 'brj83bF+RoSA+ogrgX7mQbxhmFcoZN9OGaJgYKsKWUt5Wqv627KkGodUK8mDepgD\n' + 'S3ZfoRQRx3iceETpcmHJvaIge6+vyDX3d9Z22jmvQ4AKv3py2CmU2UwuhOltFDwB\n' + '0ddtb39vgwrJxaGfiMRHpEP1DfNLWHAnA69/pgZPwIggidS+iBPUhgucMp8CAwEA\n' + 'AaNjMGEwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgEGMA8GA1UdEwEB/wQFMAMBAf8wHQYDVR0OBBYE\n' + 'FGnTGpQuQ2H/DZlXMQijZEhjs7TdMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFGnTGpQuQ2H/DZlXMQij\n' + 'ZEhjs7TdMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQC3xz1vQvcXAfpcZlngiRWeqU8zQAMQ\n' + 'LZPCFNv7PVk4pmqX+ZiIRo4f9Zy7TrOVcboCnqmP/b/mNq0gVF4O+88jwXJZD+f8\n' + '/RnABMZcnGU+vK0YmxsAtYU6TIb1uhRFmbF8K80HHbj9vSjBGIQdPCbvmR2zY6VJ\n' + 'BYM+w9U9hp6H4DVMLKXPc1bFlKA5OBTgUtgkDibWJKFOEPW3UOYwp9uq6pFoN0AO\n' + 'xMTldqWFsOF3bJIlvOY0c/1EFZXu3Ns6/oCP//Ap9vumldYMUZWmbK+gK33FPOXV\n' + '8BQ6jNC29icv7lLDpRPwjibJBXX+peDR5UK4FdYcswWEB1Tix5X8dYu6\n' + '-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n' + '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' + 'MIIECTCCAvGgAwIBAgICEAAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwgZUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT\n' + 'MRAwDgYDVQQHDAdTZWF0dGxlMRMwEQYDVQQIDApXYXNoaW5ndG9uMSIwIAYDVQQK\n' + 'DBlBbWF6b24gV2ViIFNlcnZpY2VzLCBJbmMuMRMwEQYDVQQLDApBbWF6b24gUkRT\n' + 'MSYwJAYDVQQDDB1BbWF6b24gUkRTIGFmLXNvdXRoLTEgUm9vdCBDQTAeFw0xOTEw\n' + 'MjgxODA2NTNaFw0yNDEwMjgxODA2NTNaMIGQMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UE\n' + 'CAwKV2FzaGluZ3RvbjEQMA4GA1UEBwwHU2VhdHRsZTEiMCAGA1UECgwZQW1hem9u\n' + 'IFdlYiBTZXJ2aWNlcywgSW5jLjETMBEGA1UECwwKQW1hem9uIFJEUzEhMB8GA1UE\n' + 'AwwYQW1hem9uIFJEUyBhZi1zb3V0aC0xIENBMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOC\n' + 'AQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAvtV1OqmFa8zCVQSKOvPUJERLVFtd4rZmDpImc5rIoeBk7w/P\n' + '9lcKUJjO8R/w1a2lJXx3oQ81tiY0Piw6TpT62YWVRMWrOw8+Vxq1dNaDSFp9I8d0\n' + 'UHillSSbOk6FOrPDp+R6AwbGFqUDebbN5LFFoDKbhNmH1BVS0a6YNKpGigLRqhka\n' + 'cClPslWtPqtjbaP3Jbxl26zWzLo7OtZl98dR225pq8aApNBwmtgA7Gh60HK/cX0t\n' + '32W94n8D+GKSg6R4MKredVFqRTi9hCCNUu0sxYPoELuM+mHiqB5NPjtm92EzCWs+\n' + '+vgWhMc6GxG+82QSWx1Vj8sgLqtE/vLrWddf5QIDAQABo2YwZDAOBgNVHQ8BAf8E\n' + 'BAMCAQYwEgYDVR0TAQH/BAgwBgEB/wIBADAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUuLB4gYVJrSKJj/Gz\n' + 'pqc6yeA+RcAwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUEEi/WWMcBJsoGXg+EZwkQ0MscZQwDQYJKoZI\n' + 'hvcNAQELBQADggEBABauYOZxUhe9/RhzGJ8MsWCz8eKcyDVd4FCnY6Qh+9wcmYNT\n' + 'LtnD88LACtJKb/b81qYzcB0Em6+zVJ3Z9jznfr6buItE6es9wAo'... 164184 more characters, waitQueueTimeoutMS: 0, zlibCompressionLevel: 0, dbName: 'test', userSpecifiedAuthSource: false, userSpecifiedReplicaSet: true, mongoLoggerOptions: { componentSeverities: [Object], maxDocumentLength: 1000, logDestination: [Socket] }, metadata: { driver: [Object], platform: 'Node.js v18.16.0, LE', os: [Object], env: [Object] }, [Symbol(@@mdb.enableMongoLogger)]: false } }

2023-06-13T13:12:18.657-05:00   2023-06-13T18:12:18.655Z 6fda03e6-8f0c-4350-8063-f7b1fc74da5a Task timed out after 3.02 seconds

2023-06-13T13:12:18.657-05:00   END RequestId: 6fda03e6-8f0c-4350-8063-f7b1fc74da5a

2023-06-13T13:12:18.657-05:00   REPORT RequestId: 6fda03e6-8f0c-4350-8063-f7b1fc74da5a Duration: 3022.30 ms Billed Duration: 3000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 93 MB Init Duration: 466.62 ms

2023-06-13T13:12:18.749-05:00   INIT_START Runtime Version: nodejs:18.v7 Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1::runtime:26e9402591d9c467cdcc7355f843d61968f36ecb6e9ef5ab253cc21163343275
```

Based on the console logs, this tells me that the code is hanging after I create a client, and likely when I try to connect to the cluster.

Notes:

1. My Lambda and Document DB are in the same VPC. They also belong to the same security group (which I know isn't standard) but the group has the correct self-referencing inbound rule.
2. Using a shell and Cloud9, I can connect to and query DocumentDB just fine.
3. The .pem file is at the same level as my lambda, and is uploaded to Lambda in a zip file along with a node modules package.
4. There is a **miniscule** amount of data in the cluster so there is no reason for a lambda timeout in that regard, though I ended up increasing it to 10s with the same result.

Comment: To confirm that the Security Group is not causing the problem, you could temporarily open the Inbound rule to `0.0.0.0/0`. Also, makes sure there is an Outbound rule that permits All Traffic.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks! I changed the inbound rule like you said, as well as confirmed the All Traffic outbound rule. Unfortunately, I still get a timeout when connecting.

Comment: Are you sure you are testing with _exactly_ the same code? The URI looks a bit strange around `@.cluster-cuz2po50vpwx` -- what's that period doing there?

Comment: It was an issue with the URI - I was connecting to the cluster instead of the instance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue. I added the VPC of Document DB to Lambda and still got some error. What worked for me is that I increased the Lambda memory from 512 to 624 and it worked for me